# Kotlin User Able to Interact With Text Fields

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have an issue where when the user hits the either the Log In or Create Account button, and then when they hit the `btn_back` button, the user is able to interact with the EditText field for a brief moment. This causes the view to go to the Log In or Create Account page. Is there a way to disable ALL interaction when the back button is selected? I tried `.isEnabled = false` and`getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);`
 but this doesnt seem to fix the issue of the user being able to interact with the 
EditText field.

LoginActivity.kt

```
 class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private var buttonState = true

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            //        declare the animation
            signUpAnimation()
            logInAnimation()
            logoAnimation()
            valueAnimatorEmailBack()

            email_address.visibility = View.GONE
            tv_password.visibility = View.GONE
            btn_back.visibility = View.GONE

            btn_sign_up.setOnClickListener {
                signUpUser()
                backAnimmation()
                emailAddressAnimation()
            }

            btn_log_in.setOnClickListener {
                doLogin()
                emailAddressAnimation()
                backAnimmation()
            }

            btn_back.setOnClickListener {

                buttonState = true

                startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edt_style"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/log_in_with_email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edt_style"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_log_in"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn_style"
        android:text="@string/log_in"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_log_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/round_btn_style"
        android:text="@string/create_account"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_sign_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back_style"
        android:text="@string/back"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean your btn_back or Android's back button?

Comment: @vilpe89 yes when btn_back is activated

Comment: Was able to figure it out-just put a countdown with the getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)

Answer (score 0):

In simple, you can avoid all user interactions by using a custom progress bar with a full-screen window whenever an API call or a button click is triggered.

[Android ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar)

*Due to low reputation, I have used the answer section instead of Comment*